# AssociateWith Filtering a Linq2Sql context with

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to SQL and I have a root table that hold languages used by my application

All other tables have a foreign key to this table.

My idea was to filter the context according to the language

So I used this code

> DataLoadOptions options = new
>   DataLoadOptions();
>
> options.AssociateWith< Language>(l =>
>   l.ID == 1);

Why am I receiving this error?

**Subquery is not supported on 'ID' of type '.....Language'.**

Actually I want to load only one row from this table and all my context will go accordingly

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why don't you write your normal `from t in db.Table where t.Language.Id == 1 select t` type of query?

Comment: I guess there is always another way doing things... This idea of having a general filter at the context level is really seducing and I don't want bother writing this "Where" cause for each of my statements again and again.

On the other hand, there is something that I do not understand with AssociateWith and I eager to clarify